# optimal way to calculate all nodes at distance less than k from m given nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph

A graph of size `n` is given and a subset of size `m` of it's nodes is given . Find all nodes which are at a `distance <=k` from ALL nodes of the subset .

eg . A->B->C->D->E is the graph ,  `subset` = {A,C} ,  `k` = 2.

Now , E is at distance <=2 from C , but not from A  , so it should not be counted .

I thought of running Breadth First Search from each node in subset , and taking intersection of the respective answers .
Can it be further optimized ?

I went through many posts on SO , but they all direct to kd-trees which i don't understand , so is there any other way ?

Comment: Sorry I mis-understood your problem so deleted the confusing comment.

Comment: @MohitJain: you were right , k-d tree concept can be applied here

Comment: You might want to ask this over on http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: so can it be migrated or would i have to repost there ?

Comment: Moderators can migrate it. You can flag it for their attention if you'd like (although deleting it and reposting it on the applicable site is better if you're sure it's the right move). Although they're very likely not to migrate this, as this is on topic here (as well as on CS). Just don't post the same question on both sites, as that's not allowed.

Comment: @Dukeling: ok , so i will wait for 1 day , if i don't get any answers i will delete from here and post on computer science

Comment: Is that a directed graph?

Comment: Is this a one time query or will you be doing it with the same graph for different values of k?

Comment: How many edges are there? And is the graph of a specific type. Your example of a line graph is far easier to resolve than other types of graphs.

Comment: Are there many queries? IE: search for different set of m values, or different k values or where m or k changes, but where the graph stays the same. There are some possible optimizations in that case.

Comment: graph stays the same , and yes there are many querries

Comment: An example of what kind of queries and an estimate as to how many of them might be useful. Though the main optimization there would if k varies, in which case you can run a full BFS search once for each node and store the result partitioned by k. If you know all the queries ahead of time, there are other optimizations. Otherwise, it doesn't seem like there are any major optimizations that can be made.

Comment: no ,  queries are not known ahead of time , k is variable and so is the set .

Comment: Expanded my answer for that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two non-asymptotic (I believe) optimizations:

1. If you're done with BFS from one of the subset nodes, delete all nodes that have distance > k from  it
2. Start with the two nodes in the subset whose distance is largest to get the smallest possible leftover graph

Of course this doesn't help if k is large (close to n), I have no idea in that case. I am positive however that k/d trees are not applicable to general graphs :)

Comment: @Nuclearman Hm, but then you can't remove the nodes from the subgraph, so your BFS is not really pruned, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nuclearman Sure, but if you remove those nodes, you can no longer do a BFS from another node, because it might be inside the d radius around the starting point of your first search

Comment: @Nuclearman I don't get how that would work if you're no longer connected to the graph because you were inside the radius of the first starting point. Sorry maybe I'm misunderstanding your algorithm

Comment: A fair point, what I had in mind would require preprocessing to work properly now that I think about it more, and preprocessing allows for more possibilities than just that.

Comment: @Nuclearman I would be highly interested in a good approach to this problem as you can imagine, so make sure you write an answer if you come up with something :)

Comment: Very well, posted an answer that's perhaps a bit more output sensitive. Can't seem to resolve the case where k is large, or really just the case where the the size of the final solution is O(N). Seems the only optimization there is in the case of where there are many queries.

Answer (score 0):

Nicklas B's optimizations can be applied to both of the following optimizations.

Optimization #1: Modify BFS to do the intersection as it runs rather than afterwords.

The BFS and intersection seems to be the way to go. However, there is redudant work being done by the BFS. Specicially, it is expanding nodes that it doesn't need to expand (after the first BFS). This can be resolved by merging the intersection aspect into the BFS.

The solution seems to be to keep two sets of nodes, call them "ToVisit" and "Visited", rather than label nodes visited or not.

The new rules of the BFS are as followed:

1. Only nodes in ToVisit are expanded upon by the BFS. They are then moved from ToVisit to Visited to prevent being expanded twice.
2. The algorithm returns the Visited set as it's result and any nodes left in the ToVisit are discarded. This is then used as the ToVisit set for the next node.
3. The first node either uses a standard BFS algorithm or ToVisit is the list of all nodes. Either way, the result becomes the second ToVisit set for the second node.

It works better if The ToVisit set is small on average, which tends to be the case of m and k are much less than N.

Optimization #2: Pre-compute the distances if there are enough queries so queries just do intersections.
Although, this is incompatible with the first optimization. If there are a sufficient number of queries on differing subsets and k values, then it is better to find the distances between every pair of nodes ahead of time at a cost of O(VE).

This way you only need to do the intersections, which is O(V*M*Q), where Q is the number of queries, M is the average size of the subset over the queries and V is the number of nodes. If it is expected to the be case that O(M*Q) > O(E), then this approach should be less work. Noting the two most distant nodes are useful as any k equal or higher will always return the set of all vertices, resulting in just O(V) for the query cost in that case.

The distance data should then be stored in four forms.

- The first is "kCount[A][k] = number of nodes with distance k or less from A". This provides an alternative to Niklas B.'s suggestion of "Start with the two nodes in the subset whose distance is largest to get the smallest possible leftover graph" in the case that O(m) > O(sqrt(V)) since finding the smallest is O(m^2) and it may be better to avoid trying to find the best choice for the starting pair and just pick a good choice. You can start with the two nodes in the subset with the smallest value for the given k in this data structure. You could also just sort the nodes in the subset by this metric and do the intersections in that order.
- The second is "kMax[A] = max k for A", which can be done using a hashmap/dictionary. If the k >= this value, then this this one can be skipped unless kCount[A][kMax[A]] < (number of vertices), meaning not all nodes are reachable from A.
- The third is "kFrom[A][k] = set of nodes k distance from A", since k is valid from 0 to the max distance, an hashmap/dictionary to an array/list could be used here rather than a nested hashmap/dictionary. This allows for space and time efficient*** creating the set of nodes with distance <= k from A.
- The fourth is "dist[A][B] = distance from A to B", this can be done using a nested hashmap/dictionary. This allows for handling the intersection checks fairly quickly.

*** If space isn't an issue, then this structure can store all the nodes k or less distance from A, but that requires O(V^3) space and thus time. The main benefit however is that it allow for also storing a separate list of nodes that are greater than k distance. This allows the algorithm use the smaller of the sets, dist > k or dist <= k. Using an intersection in the case of dist <= k and set subtraction in the case of dist <= k or intersection then set subtraction if the main set has the minimize size.

Comment: this is exactly is thought and wanted some another algorithm

Comment: Expanded the answer to provide possible optimizations in the case of many queries (Omega(V), ideally Omega(V^2)).

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a new node (let's say `s`) and connect it to all the `m` given nodes.
2. Then, find all the nodes which are at a distance less than or equal to k+1 from `s` and subtract m from it. `T(n)=O(V+E)`

Comment: This is the same thing as a multi-source BFS, and obviously won't work in this case. Read the question. _All_ the nodes have to be at maximum a distance `k` away, and in many cases your technique will account for nodes not satisfying this condition.